# Ternary conditional operator within TD in JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following ternary conditional operator within td:

```
for (var i = pagina * tamanhoPagina; i < data.length && i < (pagina + 1) *  tamanhoPagina; i++) {
    Ida = data[i][0];
    Paraa = data[i][9];
    Stat = data[i][10];

.append($(`<td class="table__content" data-heading="Assunto" data-alerta="${ Ida }, ${ Paraa }"  ${ Stat } != "0"?" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 90%" ":" style="font-weight:normal; font-size: 90%" ">`).append(data[i][2]))
)
```

When returning the data from the database, the data that has the variable $ {Stat} other than zero should be in bold, those that are equal to zero should be in normal color.

But td are always in bold regardless of whether the variable is zero or non-zero.

Comment: Just look at the syntax highlighting on the code you've posted. It's very clearly, blatantly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
`... ${ Stat } != "0"?" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 90%" ":" style="font-weight:normal; font-size: 90%" "> ...`
```

Every part of this string template is a string literal, except for the `${ Stat }`, which is an interpolated variable. You have to put all the variable expressions into the `${ }` for it to be evaluated. And since the only thing you want to change is `normal` to `bold`, you can deduplicate that a lot:

```
`<td ... style="font-weight: ${ Stat != 0 ? 'bold' : 'normal' }; font-size: 90%">`
```